# Next JS SEO dynamic Title

Tags: next.js

Im using a custom `app.js` and setting the `SEO fields` inside the head tag. I noticed that on the initial load the SEO title and other information are set in the head tags and when using the `router` to redirect to a new page, the SEO set initially will be there in the head tags but the title changes to the URL of the new route.

for example, the initial load the title of the tab would be `WELCOME` and the user clicks on a button that would redirect to `someDomain.com/HEY`. Now the `WELCOME` title is overwritten by `someDomain.com/HEY`, however, if I refresh the page when in the `HEY` page, I can see `WELCOME` **title** till the `HEY` page API calls are done.

As a temp fix, I am setting a title for all these pages in the respective head tags and the other fields have to be common. is this a good approach to set the SEO fields?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using `next-seo` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-seo).

It allows you to have a default config used for every page and override it where needed.